# Dialogflow Webhooks: How to resolve a webhook status code 14 [UNAVAILABLE]?

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Dialog webhookStatus:

```json
"webhookStatus": {
   "code": 14,
   "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
```

Nginx log/access:

```
[11/Aug/2020:06:29:59 +0000] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 57357 "-" "Google-Dialogflow"
```

My urls.py code is

```
path('webhook/', haniumapp.views.webhook, name='webhook'),
```

And here is my view.py code:

```
 # Intent name is Welcome.
def welcome():
    # JSON response.
    response = {
        'fulfillmentText' : 'welcome!! nice to meet you.'
    }
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)


# HERE is webhook service
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req = json.loads(request.body)

        #get request.action
        action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')

        #get request.param
        params = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters')

        # move action
        if action == 'welcome':
            return welcome()
```

I cannot figure out why my Dialogflow webhookStatus is UNAVAILABLE.

I use a nginx-uwsgi-django server. At least the call as such seems to work. For example: `mywebsite/webhook` is working just fine. It also works with https.

Comment: Please put text as text instead of images. It is easier to read, you can copy it and stackoverflow can also find the post better because the content has an impact on the search engine. For now, I have done it for you.

You may want to add a little bit more detail on the part where you say "mywebsite/webhook is working" because above you say that you get the error? So does it work or not? It is not clear. Please update it to clarify.

Comment: Your getting a 500 error when the post is hitting your service. I'm not savvy with python to see it myself, but have you tested the same endpoint with an example JSON packet as a post to see what http response you are getting. Insomnia can send a JSON packet down as the post body and will give you the http response codes

Comment: F.Müller - thank you! It is better to read than before.

Comment: Captain Wizard - it is good way to figure out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use nohup to start django and get nohup.out (logging txt?)
In nohup.out, post is come!
That means
dialogflow -> nginx -> django (ok)
But there is a tabspaceerror at view.py
def webhook
So i fix And it works!!!

To fix error, try to check log